# Targeting parent nested element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use pure CSS to create a drop down menu. However I am struggling with the correct selector and parent element. I am trying to target the `ul` in a different div from the `checkbox`. The common parent is `.site-header` and [I'm pretty sure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) I need to use `~` but I have tried loads of combinations with no luck.

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.site-nav-toggle #nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: none;
}

.site-nav-toggle #nav-toggle:checked~.navbar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="site-brand">
    ...
  </div>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="site-nav-toggle">
    <label for="nav-toggle">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put the `checkbox` input just before `.navbar`?

Then you will have to use `#nav-toggle:checked + .navbar`.

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: none;
}

#nav-toggle:checked + .navbar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="site-brand">
    ...
  </div>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" />
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="site-nav-toggle">
    <label for="nav-toggle">Menu</label>
  </div>
</header>
```